# Syntax Error issue with Jquery JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a request being made to the Steam WebAPI via Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   url: myurl,
   dataType: 'json', 
   success: success,
   cache: true
});
```

And this is the response I get from the Steam Community servers (truncated):

```
{
"result": {
    "status": 1,
    "num_results": 25,
    "total_results": 500,
    "results_remaining": 475,
    "matches": [
        [[OMMITTED FOR BREVITY]]
```

But Chrome is giving me this error (and doesn't run the success function):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

(This error is for line 2 - "result": { )

Am I missing something?

Comment: It looks like you're calling something that isn't actually JSONP.

Comment: It's not JSONP, it's just normal JSON. Why would that make this result in failure?

Comment: success is the function that gets when the request gets completed successfully. If it makes any difference, the success function is dynamically assigned (this is all inside a function).

Comment: What is the result if you paste the resulting text into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: are both ressources placed on the same domain/port?

Comment: @Nick what is the URL that Json is hosted on?

Comment: @thenewseattle The url is hosted on a remote source. The full URL that is being called in this case is: http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/v0001/?account_id=65172435&matches_requested=25&key=[key_ommitted]&format=json&json=jQuery110205507024014368653_1384305203368

Comment: @Nick 401 Unauthorized error, when I click your link

Comment: @Dr.Molle No. The URL that JSON is being pulled from is hosted by a remote company that I have no control over.

Comment: @Nick I do not see any JSON in that link

Comment: @Nick http://api.steampowered.com/IDOTA2Match_570/GetMatchHistory/v0001/?account_id=65172435&matches_requested=25&key=[key_ommitted]&format=json&json=jQuery110205507024014368653_1384305203368

Comment: @Nick there is no JSON in that link.

Comment: @thenewseattle It only returns JSON if you have a valid API Key for this web API. Thats why there is an omitted portion of the URL in the &key= part because I'm not able to distribute my key publicly. But trust me, it returns JSON. I can upload temporarily a full copy-paste of the entire JSON data I get from that link if you'd like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41064/discussion-between-thenewseattle-and-nick)

Comment: @Nick I opened a chatroom

Comment: Where does this come from: `json=jQuery110205507024014368653_1384305203368` , is it a part of `myurl`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QGptrQhH <- Full JSON output

Comment: @Dr.Molle Jquery is automatically adding that token. Not part of the url itself.

Answer (score 1):

The requested URL(taken from the comments) contains this part: `json=jQuery110205507024014368653_1384305203368`

This obviously is a result of a different request with the settings:

```
   dataType: "jsonp", 
   jsonp: "json"
```

(jQuery wouldn't add this parameter independently without these settings)

In this case the expected response-format is **jsonp**(not **json**) , but the response is **json**( what results in the error).

Comment: It's not the result of a different request. The code I put in the question is the code that is being used. That's why I can't get to the bottom of this issue. It returns JSON data but it still gives me the bad syntax error.

Comment: As I said, **jQuery wouldn't add this parameter independently without these settings** . However, it's not possible for me to request the ressource directly to inspect the headers, assuming there will no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header be sent that matches your domain you will not be able to access the JSON at all, JSONP would be the only option in this case.

Comment: This 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' piece is the reason the syntax is the way it is. I have no idea what this _actually_ means, but if I do it another way it gives me this error. Can you just briefly elaborate on what this is?